# Reset Filenumber for new folder in Recurse Filerename Powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am working on a powershell batch file.

I want to rename all the files in a certain amount of folders. I need to rename it to a certain part of the folder name followed by an incremental number.  So far i managed to create a rename command in powershell that also add numbers to the files.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter "*.jpg" | %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}-{1}.jpg' -f ($_.FullName.substring(18,8) -replace("-","")) ,$x++)}
```

This works well how ever i want to reset the number back to 1 for each separate folder. At the moment i keep numbering up trough different folders. How do i reset $x back to 1 when i change folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can't be sure that each directory is enumerated at ones, I would create a hashtable to keep track of the index. Something like:

```
$Directories = @{}
Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter "*.jpg" | ForEach {
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}-{1}.jpg' -f ($_.FullName.substring(18,8) -replace("-","")) ,++$Directories[$_.DirectoryName])
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, +1. But you could omit the ForEach `Get-ChildItem -r -filter "*.jpg" | Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}-{1}.jpg' -f ($_.FullName.substring(18,8) -replace("-","")) ,++$Directories[$_.DirectoryName]} -WhatIf`

Comment: Thank you for your replies, works like a charm. Sometimes it skipped the filename-1.jpg and started with filename-2.jpg. I fixed this by adding a sort.